# getting java.util.NoSuchElementException when using Scanner

Tags: java, exception, java.util.scanner

I'm solving a SPOJ problem. It's about Caesar cipher. I input a character ( anything uppercase character in the alphabel) and a integer number in single line, then the result is a character at index of the input character + integer number.

For example :

```
Input: B 10  => Output: L.
```

My code run successfully in my NetBeans IDE . But when I try to submit my code at https://ideone.com/ I get an error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1540)
    at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

I can not make out what I'm wrong.

I try to fix it in hours, but everthing has not changed. so please help me

here is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        int length = alphabet.length();

        String input = scn.nextLine();
        String[] parts = input.split(" ");
        String chuNhapVao = parts[0];
        int currentCharIndex = alphabet.indexOf(chuNhapVao);
        int plusIndex = Integer.parseInt(parts[1]);
        int afterPlusIndex = currentCharIndex + plusIndex;
        int finalIndex;
        if(afterPlusIndex < length - 1){
            finalIndex = afterPlusIndex;
        }
        else{
            finalIndex = afterPlusIndex - (length - 1) - 1;
        }  
        char finalChar = alphabet.charAt(finalIndex);
        System.out.println(finalChar);

    }
}
```

Comment: Did you fill the input box right under the code section before running it?

Comment: Just because this kind of executor doesn't wait during the programm for an input, you have to give the input BEFORE you run

Comment: It run succesfully when I fill the input. And I have just tried to submit my code to SPOJ and it has been accepted, thanks you so much :)

Comment: thanks you so much two friends :)